# Coding Bug in python

Tags: python

So this code uses a range and checks each value to see if it is a prime number.

The problem with this is that if the start value isn't `1` then there is an error of `"IndexError: list index out of range"` but using a starting value of `1` works fine. What should I do?

```
start = 2
stop = 20

range_pn = list(range(start, stop + 1))
list_pn = []
num_order = 0
pn_checklist = []

while num_order < stop:
    rand_num = range_pn[num_order]
    divisor = rand_num
    while divisor > 0:
        num_check = (rand_num) % (divisor)
        if num_check == 0:
            pn_checklist.append(rand_num)
        divisor -= 1
    if pn_checklist.count(max(pn_checklist)) <= 2:
        list_pn.append(rand_num)
    num_order += 1

print(list_pn)
```

Comment: num_order is going from 0..19 - so 2 values, range_pn will only have 2..20 - 19 items, so you'll get an index error when `num_order==19`

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. Python is clear from the tag you've added, every single post on this site containing code has a *coding bug*, and your personal history or knowledge level is meaningless. Your title should describe the question or problem clearly enough that the title will be useful to future readers here seeing it in a list of search results. *What should I do?* is also a non-meaningful question, unless *fix the error in your code so it doesn't happen* would be a good enough answer to satisfy you.

Comment: "but using a starting value of 1 works fine. What should I do?" Well, use a start value of 1.

Comment: sorry for being vague but thank you for the feedback, I'll be sure to be more specific in future questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Loop is running more than the length of range_pn.

> Below line of code:
>
> ```
> range_pn = list(range(start, stop + 1))
> print(range_pn)
> ```
>
> produces the output:
>
> ```
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
> ```

And the length of the list is:

```
print(len(range_pn))

Output:
19
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start from `2` to `20`, the length of `range_pn` is `19` i.e. `19` items are present in the list.

`range_pn = list(range(start, stop + 1))`

As your are checking `num_order < stop` condition, which means that you have to iterate loop `20` time because value of `num_order` is set to `0` and value of `stop` is `20`. 
You are extracting item from list by index, so it will give IndexError when index is `19` because list have `19` items i.e. from index `0` to index `18`

`rand_num = range_pn[num_order]`

According to me change condition to fix `IndexError` Issue.

Example: `while num_order+start < stop:`

---

Following method is to find out is number is **prime** or not.

Divide input number from '2' to `number/2` because if number is not prime then is should divisible by number in between `2` to `number/2`.

```
def is_number_prime(number):
    """
    number must be positive integer greater than 1
    """
    for divisor in range(2, number//2+1):
        if number%divisor == 0:
            return False
    return True
```